How to deal with question posts containing several different questions?
Especially from new users, we often get questions which are actually several questions in one post.  
What is the best way to deal with them?

Previous discussion about this: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/426/should-we-split-up-posts-that-ask-many-questions-at-once

These questions don't work well with our format: They break the "duplicate" process, and especially cause problems when they get great partial answers.
Please DON'T ANSWER all questions in one answer post. You will be duplicating work, and produce content that will be useful to very few people. Most likely your post will be deleted and your effort wasted. Also, it will be hard to move great answers to related questions.
If you still want to help the asker, there are different strategies to deal with these questions:

Salvage interesting bits.
If there is a new, interesting question in the post, edit the question to narrow it to this question (and optionally post an answer). Advise the asker to create new posts for any remaining unanswered questions, or even consider posting remaining questions as your own and link them in a comment on the primary.
Close as duplicate
If the whole post is a composite of duplicates, close it as a duplicate of one of them. Consider posting references to other relevant questions.
Vote to close as "low quality", "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking".
If there is nothing worth keeping about the question, downvote and vote to close with the best fitting of the above reasons. Please consider advising the user how to improve their post.


That sounds good.
